# Sony Spresense SDK Tensorflow Lite - Person Detection

Tags: tensorflow, sdk, tensorflow-lite, sony, spresense

I am trying to do the person detection using camera using tensorflow lite in spresense board. This is a sample program from sony developers in spresense website under examples of spresense sdk cli/gui examples for tensorflow lite.

Under this program they have made of examples/tf_person_detection to config. But when try to run this command , we are getting error as this file doesn't exist.

They have mentioned at the start to enable the tensorflow LM in Kconfig of spresense. We are not sure on how to exactly do that.

Can any please help us out here on how to create the tf_example file and configure the Kconfig with tensorflow LM.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide more details? (are you using open source code? error messages?) It's difficult to comment without more detailed information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.